# ORA-01555 error when updating 200 million rows with BULK COLLECT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bulk-load

I have the following PL/SQL code, which updates one column of each row in a table with about 200 million rows. I use BULK COLLECT to repeatedly fetch 150,000 rows from the table and update the rows. I do a commit after 50,000 updates.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR jobs_cursor IS 
        SELECT e.ID, e.PTI, e.CAT, e.JOBNAME, e.JOBDATE, e.WORK_DESCRIPTION
                FROM JOB e 
                WHERE length(e.WORK_DESCRIPTION) > 1000;

    TYPE JOBS_TYPE IS TABLE OF jobs_cursor%ROWTYPE;
    v_jobs JOBS_TYPE;
    fetch_jobs_limit PLS_INTEGER := 150000;

    trimmed_work_description VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR);
    sub_string_work_description_left VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
    sub_string_work_description_right VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
    update_counter NUMBER := 0;
    commit_counter NUMBER := 50000;

BEGIN
    OPEN jobs_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH jobs_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_jobs LIMIT fetch_jobs_limit;
        EXIT WHEN v_jobs.COUNT = 0;

        FOR idx IN 1..v_jobs.COUNT
        LOOP
            trimmed_work_description := ' ';

            IF v_jobs(idx).WORK_DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN
                trimmed_work_description := TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM v_jobs(idx).WORK_DESCRIPTION);
            END IF;

            IF length(trimmed_work_description) <= 1000 THEN
                UPDATE JOBS j SET j.WORK_DESCRIPTION = trimmed_work_description WHERE j.ID = v_jobs(idx).ID;

                update_counter := update_counter + 1;
                IF mod(update_counter, commit_counter) = 0 THEN
                    COMMIT;
                    update_counter := 0;
                END IF;
                CONTINUE;

            ELSIF length(trimmed_work_description) > 1000 THEN
                sub_string_work_description_left := SUBSTR(trimmed_work_description, 1, 1000);
                sub_string_work_description_right := SUBSTR(trimmed_work_description, 1001, 2000);
            END IF;

            UPDATE JOBS j SET j.WORK_DESCRIPTION = sub_string_work_description_left WHERE j.ID = v_jobs(idx).ID;
            INSERT INTO JOBS j VALUES ("SEQUENCE_JOBS".NEXTVAL, j.PTI, j.CAT, j.JOBNAME, j.JOBDATE, sub_string_work_description_right);

            update_counter := update_counter + 1;
            IF mod(update_counter, commit_counter) = 0 THEN
                COMMIT;
                update_counter := 0;
            END IF;

        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    CLOSE jobs_cursor;
END;
```

The code runs for several hours, but then Oracle raises an `ORA-01555 - Snapshot too old - Rollback segment number 14 with name xxxx too small`.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my PL/SQL? I already did the Google research and found some threads saying that this error could be avoided by expanding the UNDO table space, however this is not an option in my case. Thus, I need to modify the PL/SQL code.

Comment: You should get an error at this line: `IF v_jobs(idx).MESSAGE IS NOT NULL THEN`. `MESSAGE` does not exist in record.

Comment: Did I not show you a technique for doing this using redefinition vs transformation in another thread...?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That was a typo, sorry. Message is not correct. I corrected the code.

Comment: @BobC Yes you did, but I just wanted to know why the error is raised by Oracle. I'm new to Oracle and I would like to learn as much as possible from my mistakes. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain me why the error is raised with my code so that I can avoid questions like this in the future.

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01555_snapshot_old.htm

Comment: @BobC - you can tell a man about fire but he won't understand how it burns until he puts his hand in the flames.

Comment: @APC. Evidently !  I guess I need a blowtorch !!  :)

Comment: Whatever your philosophy is :D Thanks for the answers. I do not want to bother with my question because there are some alternatives and proposals already, but I just wanted to understand why this error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

On first view I don't see any reason why you make the update in a loop, it should be possible with single statements. Would be similar to this (not verified/tested)

```
update JOBS j SET 
WORK_DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM WORK_DESCRIPTION), 1, 1000)
WHERE length(WORK_DESCRIPTION) > 1000;

INSERT INTO JOBS 
SELECT SEQUENCE_JOBS.NEXTVAL, j.PTI, j.CAT, j.JOBNAME, j.JOBDATE, 
   SUBSTR(WORK_DESCRIPTION, 1001, 2000)
FROM JOBS j
WHERE length(TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM WORK_DESCRIPTION)) > 1000;
```

Comment: Wouldn't I get in trouble with the undo table space if I do the update in one UPDATE statement?

Comment: Not if the UNDO tablespace is large enough, But you're in trouble already, because it is the intermediate commits which are causing the ORA-01555 errors. So why not try a different approach which will avoid the problem *you actually have right now* ?

Comment: I have to do the update on each of the 200 million rows. I already did a COUNT(*) on the selected rows.

Comment: @APC What do you propose?

Comment: Try Wernfried's approach. Or whatever @BoBC suggested. Why bother asking people to help you on SO if you're not going to take their advice?